# Consequences of list indexing with different types in R

Tags: r, performance, list, indexing, types

There are at least three ways to get the first element of a list in R: `lst[[1]]`, `lst[[1L]]`, and `lst[[T]]`. (In English, it works out nicely that "top" begins with a T.) Similarly there are a corresponding three ways to get the rest of a list: `lst[-1]`, `lst[1L]`, and `lst[-T]`. It seems that indexing with `1` (a floating point value) is by far the most popular way to do either of these things, but why? Also, what is a good benchmark to test the efficiency of any of these?

By benchmark, I mean the kind described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)), for example.

Comment: Indexing works two ways: by name (if `character`) or by position (something that can be coerced to `integer`). The purest is likely `1L`, but I don't think there is much of a measurable difference with `1`. The reason `T`(`RUE`) works is that `as.integer(T)` returns 1L. and `-T` also yields an `integer`.

Comment: @r2evans I am curious about what I guess might be the differences in overhead between, for `1`, converting the string `1` in the source to `double` then to `integer` vs., for `1L`, converting the string `1L` to `integer`---i.e., one conversion instead of two. But maybe my guess is wrong. Anyway, the _R Language Definition_ says nothing about indexing with `double` for `[[` and says that `double` vectors are converted to `integer` vectors for `[`.

Comment: [`microbenchmark`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html) is good for showing minor differences (or lack thereof).

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for pointing out that package. However, one still needs a function to test with it. Is it sufficient to try`[` and `[[` on different length lists, for example?

Comment: `somevec <- sample(1000); microbenchmark(int=somevec[1L], dbl=somevec[1], lgl=somevec[T], times=10000)` will show you that integers and doubles have effectively equal performance, whereas the logical is rather heinous.